# django-allauth passwords with social registration

Tags: django, django-allauth

Basically, the goal is to have valid username/password pair for each registered user.

I think the proper way to do that is to create custom form for social signup.The default workflow for social signup is:

1. User clicks "Sign in with PROVIDER_NAME";
2. User gives access to my app on provider's site;
3. Site redirects him to my app where he should fill additional fields like username etc. and complete registration.

And I need to ask user for passwords too at the last step. Form should validate that passwords and save it to user.

Any ideas? Have no idea how can it be implemented with custom form or adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of allauth, is to avoid the user to create a new username/password for your site.

However, you can configure a form to add that information.
Set up the form you want to show to the user.

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'project.forms.MyUserForm'
```